# Video lighting layout planning software

Tags: video, photography

Is there a software package for Mac, Linux, or Windows that shows how to set up lighting or even shoots for video productions? Recently I have seen Mac software for photographers but that is very specific to photography equipment only.

Comment: 3D would be better, lighting on faces as well as directional. 2D would only handle an overhead map but no real visuals.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite a lot of work, but possibly worth it for other benefits, but you could model your set/environment in Blender and then try out your lighting and camera positions using it.

The additional benefits are that you can greenscreen and/or generate special effects with the same model.  It has been used for movies such as [Project London](http://projectlondonmovie.com/).

[Blender](http://www.blender.org) is a Free, Open Source, Cross Platform and very powerful 3D Modelling, Animation & Rendering tool.  It allows you to position cameras and lights (of several different types) and animate their motions as well as the motion of scene elements.

Comment: Interesting idea, I have heard of this one.